# Trouble Installing Selenium IDE in Firefox 44

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am not able to install Selenium IDE in Firefox 44.0.2. I'm installing the Firefox plugin from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/. It appears to install correctly. I do not get any error messages. I restarted Firefox after the installation. But, it does not appear under Tools-Selenium IDE as it should (see http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp). After more testing, it appears that I am not able to install any extension that requires a restart.

Comment: What version of selenium IDE is it trying to install?

Comment: It's trying to install 2.9.1. This is the version that the selenium web site points to http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Just FYI, Selenium IDE is not compatible with Firefox 55 anyway (https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/in-search-of-the-selenium-ides-successor-33bc7eaefe7f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by:

1. Starting Firefox in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)
2. Clicking the menu button
3. Clicking "help" and then selecting "Restart with Add-ons Disabled"

I'm guessing I had another extension that was interfering. I'd guess the Norton Security extension because it's the only one I've installed recently.

Comment: I have another solution. The above fix worked with Firefox developer edition. When I got Selenium working, I started seeing error messages that were being caused by the fact that I was using Firefox developer edition so I uninstalled it and installed the normal Firefox. I had the same issue installing the Selenium IDE add-on, but the above fix didn't work. What ended up working was installing Firebug first.

Answer (score 1):

This worked on Firefox 51 and 53, with Selenium IDE 2.9.1:

- At the stack/three lines menu (**☰**), press "Customize";
- Drag the Selenium IDE icon from the "*Additional Tools and Features*" pane into the icon panel;
- Restart Firefox.

Both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, for a side window, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, for a separate window, should now work, as well as the Selenium IDE icon and *Tools* menu.

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox 54. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to bypass the site instructions and just go directly to the browser. Sometimes I have noticed that the installation sometimes doesn't work for me unless I go through the add-on manager in Firefox.

**Follow these steps:**

> 1. Open Firefox
> 2. Click on the stack icon just below the red "X"
> 3. Click on "Add-Ons"
> 4. Click "Get Add-Ons" on the top left
> 5. Search for Selenium IDE 2.9.1 in the "Search all add-ons" box
> 6. Click on the "Install" button next to the selenium icon

Firefox will then restart your browser and you should see the icon added to the top right next to the stack icon. My version is currently 2.9.1 for selenium IDE, on windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I got the same results - it looks like it worked, but Selenium doesn't get installed.

Comment: I see, I would probably suggest uninstalling Firefox and reinstalling it.

Comment: I tried that, too, and had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox requires all extensions to be signed.

Seems Selenium IDE 2.9.1 is not signed yet, follow [this github issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1483).

So you could install an older version of Firefox (42) or an [developer Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) if you want to play with the unsigned IDE.

Alternatively I would give [Selenium Builder](http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/) a try. I think this is the continuation of the Selenium IDE project and supersedes it. Also it works on the latest Firefox.

Also I think Selenium IDE was more a proof of concept and never designed as project to use in production. Better might be to just hand-code Selenium tests and not use the record and playback tools at all.

Comment: I tried Selenium Builder and had the same problem. I also had the same problem with Firefox Developer edition. After experimenting, it seems that I am not able to install any extension that requires a restart. Extensions that do require a restart install successfully. Thanks for your suggestions.